# How to correctly call custom field dates into a posts_where filter using SQL statements

Tags: custom-field, sql

Currently I have the loop listing posts between two dates using the `posts_where` filter:

```
 function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
  $where .= " AND post_date >= '2000-01-01' AND post_date <= 2004-12-31' ";
  return where;
 }
 add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
 query_posts($query_string);
 while (have_posts()) :
   the_post();
   the_content();
 endwhile;
```

In a `meta_key` called `original_date` I have stored a different date for each post that I wish to use instead of the `post_date`. How do I correctly call up this `meta_key` into the `$where` query to fulfil the same purpose as the `post_date`?

```
$where .= " AND [meta_key=original_date] >= '2000-01-01' AND [meta_key=original_date] <= '2004-12-31' ";
```

For example, the following SQL query doesn't seem to work, even though correct values (`2001-10-29`, `2004-11-03`, etc.) are present in the `original_date` `meta_key` of the posts:

```
global $wpdb;
 $where .= " AND (SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key='original_date' ) >= '2000-01-01' AND (SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key='original_date' ) <= '2004-12-31' ";
```

whereas the following works fine on the same posts using their `post_date` as reference:

```
$where .= " AND post_date >= '2000-01-01' AND post_date <= 2004-12-31' ";
```

Perhaps the `meta_value` array needs to be stripped of some extraneous material in order to format the results into the same form as `post_date`? How can we approach this?

Comment: try `$where .= " AND (($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'original_date' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value >= '2000-01-01') AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'original_date' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value <= '2004-12-31')) ";`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to [AmbitiousAmoeba](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/1986/ambitiousamoeba) for the answer. The following improved code solves the problem:

```
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
   global $wpdb;

   $where .= " AND (($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'original_date' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value >= '2000-01-01') AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'original_date' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value <= '2004-12-31')) ";
   return where;
}
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
query_posts($query_string);
while (have_posts()) :
   the_post();
   the_content();
endwhile;
```

Comment: I get the following error when I run the final query in phpMyAdmin `#1054 - Unknown column 'wp_postmeta.meta_key' in 'where clause'`. Can you help with that?

Answer (score 4):

If you have
Unknown column `wp_postmeta.meta_key` in `where` clause

You probably want to join `$wpdb->postmeta` table into this query:

```
function custom_posts_join($join){
     global $wpdb;

     $join .= " LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id ";

     return $join;
}
add_filter( 'posts_join' , 'custom_posts_join');
```